# How can I log a specific child in some XML data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

```
$.get('MyPHPFileThatDownloadsAndPrintsTheXML.php', function(data) {
    console.log(data.childNodes[0]);
}, 'xml');
```

Let's say I want to log the first row's stageName. How would I go about doing this with the code I already have?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can traverse the XML like you would HTML with jQuery DOM methods :

```
$.get('MyPHPFileThatDownloadsAndPrintsTheXML.php', function(data) {
    var txt =  $(data).find('row').first().find('stageName').text();
    console.log(txt);
}, 'xml');
```

Comment: You sir are my new best friend. I will select as best answer when the timer is up! Was getting a little confused with it all but you've solved my problem. Thanks!

Comment: What would I do if I wanted the 14th row? (I only ask because I want to know what to put if it's not the first()), thanks :)

Comment: @JoelKidd - you'd do `$(data).find('row').eq(13).find('stageName').text();`

Answer (score 0):

Using pure *JavaScript* to get *XML* entries is the same as navigating any *#document* using DOM-only methods. The following example gets the *14th* row's *stageName* (14th = index `14 - 1 === 13`)

```js
function (data) {
    function getData(rowIndex, key, index) {
        return data[rowIndex].getElementsByTagName(key)[index || 0];
    }
    function getTextData(rowIndex, key, index) {
        return getData(rowIndex, key, index).textContent;
    }
    console.log(getTextData(13, 'stageName'));
}
```